# Lowest cost edge where edge weights are between 0 and 1

Tags: algorithm, graph

I am given a graph G = (V, E). Each edge has probability of failure which is equal to its edge weight. Each edge weight is between 0 and 1. I need to find the path of the lowest probability of failure. This means a path where the total weight is 1 - ((1 - w(e1))(1 - w(e2))...).

To me, this doesn't seem like a shortest path problem because the shortest path may have the highest weights. I thought that a modified Dijkstra's algorithm would work where instead of checking if `d[v] > d[u] + w(u, v)` I would check if `d[v] < d[u] + w(u, v)` but that can't possibly be it. I am stuck. Can anyone offer advice?

Comment: Take the logarithms of the *success* chances. Do you see a way to use those to transform this into a cheapest-path problem?

Comment: What's wrong with Dijkstra? Sounds like exactly what you want. It is indeed a shortest path problem.

Comment: So you're saying that because I want to maximize the chance of success, I want the minimum cost edge path, so therefore it is a dijkstra's algo problem?

Comment: @user2357112 I'm sorry, could you clarify a bit. Are you saying that when doing dijkstra's and checking the edge weights, I should check log(1-w(u, v)) instead? Would it be dijkstra's algorithm with `d[v] > d[u]*(1-w(u, v))`

Comment: @JeremyFisher: Something like that could work, although you might have that inequality backward.

Comment: This kind of question pops up every now and then, and has been answered on SO a number of times. See [e.g. here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32878028/use-shortest-path-to-calculate-probability-of-connection/32878206#32878206).